# Remove product from Flat Tables

Tags: magento

I wrote an extension that can programmatically create and delete products for a client.

Both creating and deleting worked.

The client then turned on flat tables.

Now, the creating products works, but deleting products doesn't work.

My question:  What's the correct way, if even possible, to remove a product from the flat table?

Answer (score 0):

This should work out of the box if the flat tables are build correctly.
There should be this constraint on the flat table:

```
CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT_1_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

So when a product is deleted from `catalog_product_entity` it should be deleted from the flat table also.